# clearing cache in chrome when publishing new Vue app version

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, browser-cache, cache-control

When I make any changes to the vue js application and then go live, the old version remains live. The problem goes away when the browser's cache is cleared. How can I fix this cache clearing issue

Comment: What exactly is your case? Did you deploy the app to a webserver? Then Vue part is irrelevant, the way cache behaves totally depends on webserver config.

Comment: use versioning in your js and css links.. like app.js?v=1.0.0 and if you release a new version app.js?v=1.1.0....

Comment: There is no script named app.js on the index.html page. It creates the app.js file itself. So I can't version

Comment: How accurate would it be to prevent the browser from caching with this method?

`<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />`

Comment: Tried hard refresh of browser?

Comment: It happens when you do a refresh, but the main purpose is to fix this problem while going live.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to force clearing cache in chrome when release new Vue app version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59648117/how-to-force-clearing-cache-in-chrome-when-release-new-vue-app-version)

Answer (score 1):

In chrome dev-tools under the network tab you have the option to turn cache temporarily off.